# Error on Configuring Django-oauth-plus

Tags: django, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I am getting a **400 error** when i try the example in the [docs](http://code.larlet.fr/django-oauth-plus/wiki/Home)

```
settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'oauth_provider',
'django.contrib.auth',
)

OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHODS = ['hmac-sha1',]
```

And when i do this

```
>>> from oauth_provider.models import Resource, Consumer
>>> resource = Resource(name='photos', url='/oauth/photo/')
>>> resource.save()
>>> CONSUMER_KEY = 'dpf43f3p2l4k3l03'
>>> CONSUMER_SECRET = 'kd94hf93k423kf44'
>>> consumer = Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
...                     name='http://127.0.0.1:9000', user=jane)
>>> consumer.save()


>>> from django.test.client import Client
>>> c = Client()

>>> import time
>>> parameters = {
...     'oauth_consumer_key': CONSUMER_KEY,
...     'oauth_signature_method': 'PLAINTEXT',
...     'oauth_signature': '%s&' % CONSUMER_SECRET,
...     'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
...     'oauth_nonce': 'requestnonce',
...     'oauth_version': '1.0',
...     'oauth_callback': 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/request_token_ready',
...     'scope': 'photos', 
... }
>>> response = c.get("/oauth/request_token/", parameters)
>>> response.status_code

    400
```

Am i missing something in the configuration? I cannot find a good documentation on how to do this?

Comment: You fix this? I have the same situation and not know hot to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling too with the same issue, then tried the recommended Python library at [OAuth's site](http://oauth.net/code/), **rauth**, then [followed the steps](https://rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#oauth-1-0-services) and obtained the `request_token`and the other parameters needed.

I noticed it automatically encoded the signature with HMAC-SHA1, which I think is what you would want, given the `OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHODS` variable you mentioned at the top.

Hope it helps someone.